# Exception when setting SelectedValue on CF Combobox

Tags: combobox, compact-framework, selectedvalue

I am using Compact Framework 3.5 and have the following code:

```
var timeouts = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ddlTimeout.DataSource = timeouts;
ddlTimeout.SelectedValue = 3;
```

And receive the following error on setting selected value. Where's an issue?

> Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember

Note: It works well if I use List<> of class objects as DataSource with specifying DisplayMember and ValueMember for the ComboBox.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is

> "Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty
> ValueMember."

Try this instead:

```
var timeouts = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ddlTimeout.DataSource = timeouts;
ddlTimeout.SelectedItem = 3;
```

You have to have the ValueMember set for SelectedValue to work. The documentation shows the difference:

> **`ComboBox.SelectedValue`** Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the ValueMember property
>
> **`ComboBox.SelectedItem`** Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.